# How to troubleshoot why Thunderbird rejects a PKCS#12 certificate with "Could not verify this certificate for unknown reasons"?

Tags: tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, x.509

After playing around a bit with `openssl`, I created a PKCS12 certificate which imports flawlessly in Firefox while Thunderbird "Could not verify this certificate for unknown reasons". Talk about a helpful error message here. While I managed to solve the problem (the certificate had an `extendedKeyUsage` of `emailProtection,clientAuth` while the signing CA had `emailProtection` only - why did Firefox import it then?!) in this case, I'd like to know about a less trial-and-error way to figure out why a specific certificate fails.

I could find a large number of threads and bug reports, e.g. [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mozilla.dev.tech.crypto/RiIeY-R5Q4Y), which suggest whatever library is internally used *does* actually provide more meaningful error messages, but I don't have an idea where to start calling it or whether some simple command line tools exist to achieve this. So in summary:

> How to figure out why a Mozilla product rejects importing a certificate "for unknown reasons"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last I had to do something like that, I ploughed through [NSS source code](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/src/download.html). NSS is the library which Mozilla products use for all things crypto. Ultimately, you could *compile* your own Thunderbird and run it in a debugger (or spread `printf()` calls throughout the NSS code, for some old-style analysis).

Apart from that, it is mostly guesswork. You did it quite well: by importing the same certificate into Firefox and Thunderbird, both using the same NSS code, you actually showed that the detail you were after had to be something about emails -- which then points to extended key usage and "usage rules" that NSS can attach to a given root.

At least, NSS *is* opensource. Try doing the same for Windows/IE next time...

Comment: Oh dear, that sounds like fun... I'm especially confused since that certificate should have been rejected by Firefox (it's CA doesn't have the `clientAuth` extension, and what would Firefox do about email?) and maybe tolerated by Thunderbird (why should it bother about `clientAuth` anyway). In one of the posts about this error "message" someone mentioned `pk12util`, but that only lists the contents, and `certtool` doesn't seem to cope with pkcs12 files. But why doesn't Mozilla simply output the error message that apparently _is_ generated?

Comment: To some extent, Firefox does not need to care about whatever certificate you give it to play with, because that certificate is not for it; it is for the SSL server who asks for it. Theoretically, you never have to validate or trust your own certificate.

Comment: Good point, that makes sense. Though the same should then be true for Thunderbird, since it's in the recipient's interest to validate a sent certificate...