# Trying to verify my X509 certificate "could not verify this certificate for unknown reasons"

Tags: certificates, firefox

I have created my own X509 certificate with my own CA. I am able to import the CA certificate into Firefox, but when I try to import the user's certificates I get the following:

> Could not verify this certificate for unknown reasons

I'm guessing I did something wrong while creating the certificates. Is there any way to get more information about why Firefox couldn't verify the certificates?

Comment: Identical, distinctly odd error message, `could not verify...unknown reasons` when importing PKCS12 certificate into Thunderbird http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30970/how-to-troubleshoot-why-thunderbird-rejects-a-pkcs12-certificate-with-could-no

Answer (score 1):

## Make sure the certificate has "Digital Signature" enabled

Take a look at the key usage extensions on the certificate. They are labelled *X509v3 Key Usage* by OpenSSL.

```
$ openssl x509 -in mycert.pem -text -noout
...
X509v3 Key Usage: critical
    Digital Signature, Non Repudiation
X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
    TLS Web Client Authentication, E-mail Protection
```

If the certificate can't be used for *Digital Signature* (e.g., it is for E-mail Protection only), then Firefox may not be able to use it.

[NSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS), the SSL library that Firefox and Mozilla products use, is much stricter than OpenSSL about the key usage settings.